# Unity3d 2021 crashes when trying to build AssetBundles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've just migrated my project from 2019 version to 2021.3.6f1 version and got a problem.
Unity will crash when trying to build asset bundles. No crash in 2019 version.

Buld is made by calling build asset bundle method and passing manually builded list of `AssetBundle`.

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(
   outputPath, 
   assetBundlesBuilds.ToArray(), 
   BuildAssetBundleOptions.ChunkBasedCompression, 
   AssetPreparator.BUILD_TARGET
);
```

Crash logs:

```
Obtained 29 stack frames
0x00007ff7bf08b84b (Unity) BuildAssetBundlesInternal
0x00007ff7bf08a74a (Unity) BuildAssetBundles
0x00007ff7bdbfe51a (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildAssetBundlesWithInfoInternal
0x000002b71e26a6f3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundlesWithInfoInternal (string,UnityEditor.AssetBundleBuild[],UnityEditor.BuildAssetBundleOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int)
0x000002b71e26a273 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles (string,UnityEditor.AssetBundleBuild[],UnityEditor.BuildAssetBundleOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int)
0x000002b71e269c43 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildAssetBundles (string,UnityEditor.AssetBundleBuild[],UnityEditor.BuildAssetBundleOptions,UnityEditor.BuildTarget)
0x000002b71e22b893 (Mono JIT Code) [AssetBundleCreator.cs:87] Editor.AssetBundleBuilder.AssetBundleCreator:buildAssets (string,System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Editor.AssetBundleBuilder.BundlePack>,bool) 
0x000002b71e223bcb (Mono JIT Code) [AssetPreparator.cs:194] Editor.AssetBundleBuilder.AssetPreparator:createCharacterAssetBundles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason for crash was that list of assetBundles contains paths to non-existent files. Don't know why it worked in 2019, but now it's just crashes.

Answer (score 1):

For any missing asset paths / other paths issue: delete the complete Library folder, than rebuild the Library, by just restarting the Unity, with that project, and see if it has improved, regardless. In our project case, (with about 92 different assets used) - it worked, but it depends on so many other factors, of course, as well, per each different Unity project :).